# How to secure ajax enabled wcf services from jquery client access in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf-security

I looked at many solution for basic authentication but i failed to understand. So please help me to solve this problem.
Here is my code which call wcf service

```
$.ajax({
url: "Ajaxservices/Activity.svc/getMaterials",
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json",
data: JSON.stringify({ query: query,"collegId":parseInt($('#CollegID').val()) }),
type: 'POST',
success: function (response) {
materials = []; 
map = {};
$.each(response.d, function (i, material) {
map[material.ItemName] = material;
materials.push(material.ItemName);
});
process(materials); 
} 
});
```

and this wcf service

```
#region GetMaterials
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public List<HMSEntities.Materials> getMaterials(string query, int collegId)
{
try
   {
   List<HMSEntities.Materials> materialList = activityDal.getMaterials(query,  collegId);
   return materialList;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   HMS.BasePage objPage = new BasePage();
   string msg = objPage.GetErrorInformation(ex);
   objPage.Log4Error(Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["HospID"]), msg);
   throw ex;
   }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/Home.html

Comment: thanks  Anthony Horne but  i am looking security for ajax enabled wcf serviecs..

Comment: Will oAuth not work?

Comment: no its not working...